# How do you open large heap dumps using VisualVM?

Tags: java, visualvm

I created a heap dump using VisualVM. The resulting `.hprof` file is about 6GB.

When I try to load the file in VisualVM, it gets stuck at 50%. While stuck, no additionaly resources appear to be consumed on the computer I'm using. CPU is quiet, only about half of the available memory is in use, and there isn't any IO being reported.

[jvisualvm: Stuck on “Loading Heap Dump” screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461494/jvisualvm-stuck-on-loading-heap-dump-screen) asks a similar question, but the only answer suggests creating the `.hprof` file through VisualVM (which I already did).

Are there any special settings I need to use to open a heap dump of this size?

Comment: See my answer to [similar question][1]. Will it help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318262/jvisualvm-stuck-on-loading-heap-dump-screen

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254017/tool-for-analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you to open it with [`MAT` Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) , its a powerful tool to analyze that kind of Heap dump files, beside its the common way to analyze Heap files.

Also you need to increase [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) memory in order to open that big size file, you can do that as the following:

1. Open `config.ini` file that located in MAT_HOME directory.
2. Change the value of `-Xmx` to more than `6GB`.

The Above Link contain also a tutorial to how to use `MAT`.

If `MAT` won't open the Heap file, then the file is probably corrupted.

Comment: You'll thank me again after trying it, its really powerful and easy to use :)

Comment: MAT won't open my .hprof file. It thinks the file is corrupt. Perhaps that's the same reason VisualVM won't open it.

Comment: Yes the file is corrupted.

Comment: On Mac, I needed to edit /Applications/mat.app/Contents/Eclipse/MemoryAnalyzer.ini to increase the memory.